# What is the best way to run saved model with different batch size in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I trained [Cifar10 example model from TensorFlow's repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10) with batch_size 128 and it worked fine. Then I [froze graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/816ecb7a342c25c19daa8b19627346e1fb38e56f/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py) and managed to run it with C++ just like they do it in their [C++ label image example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/754048a0453a04a761e112ae5d99c149eb9910dd/tensorflow/examples/label_image).

The only problem was that I had to artificially generate tensor of shape [128, image_height, image_width, channels] to classify single image with C++ because saved model expects input of 128 samples in a batch since that is number of samples that comes from queue.

I tried training Cifar10 example with batch_size = 1 and then I managed to      classify examples one by one when I run model with C++, but that doesn't seem like a great solution. I also tried manually changing tensor shapes in saved graph file but it didn't work.

My question is what is the best way to train model with fixed batch size (like 32, 64, 128 etc.) and then save model so that it can be used with batch size of arbitrary length? If that's not possible, then how to save model to be able to classify samples one by one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like the problem is that TensorFlow is "baking in" the batch size to other tensors in the graph (e.g. if the graph contains `tf.shape(t)` for some tensor `t` whose shape depends on the batch size, the batch size might be stored in the graph as a constant). The solution is to change your program slightly so that `tf.train.batch()` returns tensors with a variable batch size.

The `tf.train.batch()` method accepts a `tf.Tensor` for the `batch_size` argument. Perhaps the simplest way to modify your program for variable-sized batches would be to define a placeholder for the batch size:

```
# Define a scalar tensor for the batch size, so that you can alter it at
# Session.run()-time.
batch_size_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[])
input_tensors = tf.train.batch(..., batch_size=batch_size_tensor, ...)
```

This would prevent the batch size from being baked into your GraphDef, so you should be able to feed values of any batch size in C++. However, this modification would require you to feed a value for the batch size on every step, which is slightly tedious.

Assuming that you always want to train with batch size 128, but retain the flexibility to change the batch size later, you could use a [`tf.placeholder_with_default()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#placeholder_with_default) to specify that the batch size should be 128 when you *don't* feed an alternative value:

```
# Define a scalar tensor for the batch size, so that you can alter it at
# Session.run()-time.
batch_size_tensor = tf.placeholder_with_default(128, shape=[])
input_tensors = tf.train.batch(..., batch_size=batch_size_tensor, ...)
```

Comment: how to use the batch_size_tensor to define the shape of another tensor?

Comment: What about the performance while training. Having fix batch size during training will lead to internal optimizations and supplying it as a placeholder with default value during training might not optimize code for that batch_size.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need fixed batch size in the graph?

I think a good way is to build a graph with a variable batch size - by putting None as the first dimension. During training, you can then pass the batch size flag to your data provider, so it feeds the desired amount of data in each iteration.

After the model is trained, you can [export the graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/variables/index.html) using `tf.train.Saver()`, which exports the metagraph. To do inference, you can load the exported files and just evaluate with any number of examples - also just one.
Note, this is different from the frozen graph.

Comment: Reason that I'm training with fixed batch size is that tf.train.batch() (that I use for batching) receives parameter batch_size and you have to specify that number.

It seemed to me that freezing graph was the way to go. I'll try to save model with tf.train.Saver(), restore it in another session that runs inference with single sample and then freeze that graph. That should probably let me run inference on single sample after I run that graph in C++. I'm still a bit confused with TensorFlow and many of it's scripts because they're not properly documented or not officially supported.

Comment: Also, later I'd like to run inference only on single sample because I want to classify images coming in real time from camera feed.