# Changing input batch size of provided model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Sorry for the newbie question. I've tried looking for examples but most of the time it's pseudo-code/snippets I can't run and it's hard to tell what's what, especially with all the different TF workflows.

I am trying to convert a pre-trained TensorFlow Saved Model, ResNet-50 v2 (fp32), to a quantized TensorFlow Lite file and have two issues:

1. The batch size appears to be fixed at 64. i.e. the input tensor is 64x224x224x3. I would like it to be 1x224x224x3
2. There are error messages when loading/converting the Saved Model, both when using tflite_convert/toco and when using resnet_v2_50()

The model appears correct at a glance, even with the error messages, so I'm mostly concerned about the batch size modification.

The Saved Model I tried converting:

[ResNet-50 v2 (fp32) Model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/resnet#pre-trained-model)

- [SavedModel (NHWC)](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/official/20181001_resnet/savedmodels/resnet_v2_fp32_savedmodel_NHWC.tar.gz)

The Checkpoint data and .py model I tried using to generate a new Saved Model:

[ResNet V2 50^](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#pre-trained-models)

- [resnet_v2.py model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/resnet_v2.py)
- [resnet_v2_50_2017_04_14.tar.gz checkpoint](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/resnet_v2_50_2017_04_14.tar.gz)

How I converted it to .tflite in bash:

```
tflite_convert --output_file resnet_imagenet_v2_uint8_20181001.tflite --saved_model_dir . --post_training_quantize
```

This results in a reasonable model for 64x224x224x3. This might run okay for Android/iOS (haven't tried) despite the errors, but I'm trying to use it on a custom platform for experimenting.

The script I tried to generated a Saved Model with my target input shape:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.contrib.slim.nets import resnet_v2

def main():
    # Directory containing resnet_v2_50.ckpt
    ckpt_dir = "/media/resnet_v2_50_2017_04_14/"
    with tf.contrib.slim.arg_scope(resnet_v2.resnet_arg_scope()):
        input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1,224,224,3], name="input_tensor")
        output_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1,1000])

        # Create model
        # Generates errors for all Conv2D nodes like:
        # 2018-10-19 16:41:41.393976: E tensorflow/core/framework/node_def_util.cc:110] Error in the node: {{node resnet_v2_50/conv1/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](resnet_v2_50/Pad, resnet_v2_50/conv1/weights/read)
        net, end_points = resnet_v2.resnet_v2_50(input_tensor, 1000)

        # Load checkpoint data
        sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=ckpt_dir)
        with sv.managed_session() as sess:
            # Allows saving, but unexpected results:
            # sess.graph._unsafe_unfinalize() 

            # Below call fails with:
            # RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.
            tf.saved_model.simple_save(
                sess,
                "./export",
                inputs={"input_tensor": input_tensor},
                outputs={"resnet_v2_50/predictions/Softmax": output_tensor}
            )

main()
```

I think I'm doing something quite wrong, but it looks close to examples I've found online so I'm a bit lost. Using `sess.graph._unsafe_unfinalize()` allows the simple_save() to run, creating a .pb and variables/ directory under export/, but when I view it in Netron, a model viewer I found, there's many more nodes than the provided Saved Model (batch size 64) I downloaded from the tensorflow models repo. 3395 vs 1930.

Trying to convert this model anyways results in this error:

```
$ tflite_convert --output_file export.tflite --saved_model_dir . --post_training_quantize
.
.
.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tfuser/venv/bin/tflite_convert", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/tfuser/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 412, in main
    app.run(main=run_main, argv=sys.argv[:1])
  File "/home/tfuser/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/home/tfuser/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 408, in run_main
    _convert_model(tflite_flags)
  File "/home/tfuser/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 162, in _convert_model
    output_data = converter.convert()
  File "/home/tfuser/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/lite.py", line 453, in convert
    **converter_kwargs)
  File "/home/tfuser/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/convert.py", line 370, in toco_convert_impl
    input_data.SerializeToString())
  File "/home/tfuser/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/lite/python/convert.py", line 149, in toco_convert_protos
    "TOCO failed see console for info.\n%s\n%s\n" % (stdout, stderr))
RuntimeError: TOCO failed see console for info.
b'2018-10-19 17:00:58.673690: F tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/tooling_util.cc:886] Check failed: GetOpWithInput(model, input_array.name()) Specified input array "input_tensor" is not consumed by any op in this graph. Is it a typo? To silence this message, pass this flag:  allow_nonexistent_arrays\n'
None
```

So it looks like my use of input_tensor was wrong and is creating a lot of extra nodes?

My setup:

- CentOS 7
- Python 3.6.6
- TensorFlow Nightly 1.13.0.dev20181018 (CPU)

Some pages I looked at for help:

- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586471/what-is-the-best-way-to-run-saved-model-with-different-batch-size-in-tensorflow) seems to suggest changing the model to take a placeholder batch size and re-train. I don't think this is suitable if I'm using a pre-trained model.
- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49872844/how-to-load-trained-tensorflow-model-to-predict-with-different-batch-size) regenerates the frozen model with a different input placeholder.
- [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/tensorflow/comments/9aijuz/changing_the_batch_size_of_a_frozen_graph_pb/e4wlp8m) sounds good, but I'm not sure how to do it.

**Any ideas on how to achieve this? A better strategy or a fix to my script would be very appreciated and welcome.**

Secondary questions:

- The documentation for simple_save() says inputs and outputs should be a map of strings to tensors.

  - By tensor does it mean the tf.placeholder? Or a numpy array? Or a tf.Variable?
  - For the string, does it expect the name of the input and output tensors? So "input_tensor" and "resnet_v2_50/predictions/Softmax" are correct?
- Do I need to call `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` at some point? If I try to call it in the above script, it says the graph is finalized.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @dxpelou no, I wasn't able to figure either issue out. I believe there were improvements to the TFLite conversion tools recently that might fix the conversion issue, though.